# Code works with a dataframe of x70 columns and FAIL with 1000 columns (same data-structure)

Tags: python, dataframe, factor-analysis

I code a factor analysis with alphalens module that WORKS perfectly with 70 columns in the dataframe and fail when I try with 1780 columns...

I don't don't how it's possible, because it's exactly the same structure, i checked everything but the magic stoped in alphalens.

https://github.com/Ibsylonne/test_alphalens

If you have a clue or idea please let a comments bellow.

RUN

```
factor = pd.read_csv('original70columns.csv', delimiter=';')
factor['date'] = pd.to_datetime(factor.date)
factor = factor.set_index('date').stack()
factor.head()

date                      
1996-12-31  DU UH Equity      0.0
            SCL LN Equity     0.0
            BMA AR Equity     0.0
            GCLA AR Equity    0.0
            EBS AV Equity     0.0
dtype: float64
```

DOESN'T RUN

```
factor = pd.read_csv('test1780columns.csv', delimiter=';')
factor['date'] = pd.to_datetime(factor.date)
factor = factor.set_index('date').stack()
factor.head()

date                      
1996-12-31  DU UH Equity      0.0
            SCL LN Equity     0.0
            BMA AR Equity     0.0
            GCLA AR Equity    0.0
            EBS AV Equity     0.0
dtype: float64
```

For whose that are familiar with alphalens: (try with 1780 columns)

```
factor_data = get_clean_factor_and_forward_returns(
    factor,
    prices,
    quantiles=2,
    periods=(1, 5, 10,),
    max_loss=1)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
```

Quite mysterious...

any clues, ideas, let it commented bellow I_I
thank you

Comment: Can you post your test data in github or somewhere else that we could grab to run the code against, i'm thinking you may have a number being typecast as a str that you'll need to change with code to a float but i'm not sure

Comment: @oppressionslayer Thank you for your attention, It's possible but I created the data manually using a formula in excel (ln(t) - ln(t-1)) so I doubt that there is any string walking around... here is the github link  (first ever created) https://github.com/Ibsylonne/test_alphalens

Comment: Looking at your data i notice some numbers like: -6.91E or -7.77E-06, it may be adding these as strings, i'm trying to find out if it is or not, do you know how to look at all numbers in table without the formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE, i think fixed the 0's to not be NaN, but i'm still getting the error, still looking at this, but maybe what i've done so far will give you some ideas as well, let me know what you think:

```
from numpy import nan
from pandas import (DataFrame, date_range)
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from alphalens.tears import (create_returns_tear_sheet,
                      create_information_tear_sheet,
                      create_turnover_tear_sheet,
                      create_summary_tear_sheet,
                      create_full_tear_sheet,
                      create_event_returns_tear_sheet,
                      create_event_study_tear_sheet)

from alphalens.utils import get_clean_factor_and_forward_returns

# build price
# Added skip for testing, it can be removed
skip=False
prices = pd.read_csv('prices_quant.csv', delimiter=';')
prices['date'] = pd.to_datetime(prices.date)
prices = prices.set_index('date')
prices = prices.fillna(0)
print(prices)


factor = pd.read_csv('test1.csv', delimiter=';')
factor['date'] = pd.to_datetime(factor.date)
factor = factor.set_index('date').stack()
factor = factor.fillna(0)
print(factor)

try:
  factor_data = get_clean_factor_and_forward_returns(
     factor,
     prices,
     quantiles=5,
     periods=(1, 5, 10,),
     max_loss=1)
except Exception as e: 
  print(e)
  skip = True
  next 

if skip == False:
  create_full_tear_sheet(factor_data, long_short=True,)
  create_event_returns_tear_sheet(factor_data, prices,long_short=True)
  print("\nNo Errors\n")
else: 
  print("\nWe encountered an error\n")


            DU UH Equity  SCL LN Equity  BMA AR Equity  GCLA AR Equity  EBS AV Equity  OMV AV Equity  ...  RDF SJ Equity  HYP SJ Equity  AEL SJ Equity  MRP SJ Equity  EMI SJ Equity  AXL SJ Equity
date                                                                                                  ...                                                                                          
1996-12-31       0.00000            0.0        9.35256         0.00000        0.00000       11.11470  ...        0.00000        1.25522        1.06860        0.75895        0.00000        0.36700
1997-01-30       0.00000            0.0        9.68044         0.00000        0.00000       11.34016  ...        0.00000        1.25426        1.23754        0.74472        0.00000        0.40870
1997-02-27       0.00000            0.0        9.99271         0.00000        0.00000       11.75658  ...        0.00000        1.21265        1.25000        0.58482        0.00000        0.49981
1997-03-31       0.00000            0.0       11.00760         0.00000        0.00000       11.82128  ...        0.00000        1.27312        1.60597        0.73513        0.00000        0.42375
1997-04-30       0.00000            0.0       10.81243         0.00000        0.00000       10.88544  ...        0.00000        1.24338        1.73112        0.79811        0.00000        0.46649
...                  ...            ...            ...             ...            ...            ...  ...            ...            ...            ...            ...            ...            ...
2018-08-30       1.39123           63.4        4.34430         1.35635       39.73607       52.90799  ...        0.70425        6.94043        1.07509       15.33290        1.08665        0.04015
2018-09-30       1.36945           61.7        4.18581         1.66410       41.55489       56.20015  ...        0.70719        6.51431        1.15394       16.11004        1.05302        0.03670
2018-10-31       1.33406           51.9        4.43810         1.61537       40.70160       55.54638  ...        0.64929        6.11171        1.18551       15.63778        1.00880        0.03318
2018-11-29       1.35312           46.3        4.49952         1.32456       39.43278       50.48753  ...        0.68896        6.40823        1.27159       17.31443        1.06684        0.03305
2018-12-31       1.36956           46.3        4.35219         1.31402       33.23611       43.76183  ...        0.67241        5.66712        1.25163       17.11610        1.02912        0.02990

[265 rows x 1780 columns]
date                      
1996-12-31  DU UH Equity      0.000000
            SCL LN Equity     0.000000
            BMA AR Equity     0.000000
            GCLA AR Equity    0.000000
            EBS AV Equity     0.000000
                                ...   
2018-12-31  HYP SJ Equity     0.029605
            AEL SJ Equity     0.000777
            MRP SJ Equity     0.000000
            EMI SJ Equity     0.000000
            AXL SJ Equity     0.000000
Length: 471700, dtype: float64
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'

We encountered an error
```

Let me know if this helps

Original Post:
Some prices have NaN, i'm wondering if that's causing it an issue, do you know if changing those to 0 would have an effect. I'm not to sure but since it division by a string, i think that could be the root cause, but this is just a guess:

```
$ python3 code_alphalens_analysis 
            DU UH Equity  SCL LN Equity  BMA AR Equity  GCLA AR Equity  EBS AV Equity  OMV AV Equity  ...  RDF SJ Equity  HYP SJ Equity  AEL SJ Equity  MRP SJ Equity  EMI SJ Equity  AXL SJ Equity
date                                                                                                  ...                                                                                          
1996-12-31           NaN            NaN        9.35256             NaN            NaN       11.11470  ...            NaN        1.25522        1.06860        0.75895            NaN        0.36700
1997-01-30           NaN            NaN        9.68044             NaN            NaN       11.34016  ...            NaN        1.25426        1.23754        0.74472            NaN        0.40870
1997-02-27           NaN            NaN        9.99271             NaN            NaN       11.75658  ...            NaN        1.21265        1.25000        0.58482            NaN        0.49981
1997-03-31           NaN            NaN       11.00760             NaN            NaN       11.82128  ...            NaN        1.27312        1.60597        0.73513            NaN        0.42375
1997-04-30           NaN            NaN       10.81243             NaN            NaN       10.88544  ...            NaN        1.24338        1.73112        0.79811            NaN        0.46649
...                  ...            ...            ...             ...            ...            ...  ...            ...            ...            ...            ...            ...            ...
2018-08-30       1.39123           63.4        4.34430         1.35635       39.73607       52.90799  ...        0.70425        6.94043        1.07509       15.33290        1.08665        0.04015
2018-09-30       1.36945           61.7        4.18581         1.66410       41.55489       56.20015  ...        0.70719        6.51431        1.15394       16.11004        1.05302        0.03670
2018-10-31       1.33406           51.9        4.43810         1.61537       40.70160       55.54638  ...        0.64929        6.11171        1.18551       15.63778        1.00880        0.03318
2018-11-29       1.35312           46.3        4.49952         1.32456       39.43278       50.48753  ...        0.68896        6.40823        1.27159       17.31443        1.06684        0.03305
2018-12-31       1.36956           46.3        4.35219         1.31402       33.23611       43.76183  ...        0.67241        5.66712        1.25163       17.11610        1.02912        0.02990
```

Comment: You are the hero of the day ! Alphalens used "prices.csv" and joined the index with "shares.csv", at first when I tried with 70 column it works even with the NaN, but somewhere in the XXX columns and YYY row was a data name "Invalid Security" and everything was upside down.

So as you recommend, I cleaned the data (in excel sorryyy) with the command 
=(if(isnumber("bugingcell";"bugingcell"; 0), I upload the file in github, or if you have the code to do the same, I'm eager to learn !

thank you so much!